# How to add a value/data to end of each row in Unix

Tags: unix

I have `fileA`, `fileB` data as shown below

`fileA`

```
,,"user1","email"
,,"user2","email"
,,"user3","email"
,,"user4","email"
```

`fileB`

```
,,user2,location
,,user4,location
,,user1,location
,,user3,location
```

I want to search `fileA` user on `fileB` and get only location and add that one to fileA/or other file

Output expecting like

```
,,"user1","email",location
,,"user2","email",location
,,"user3","email",location
,,"user4","email",location
```

I'm trying the logic, using while get the `fileA` username and search that on `fileB` to get the location. but getting failed to add that with `fileA` back

Your help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for user in `awk -F\" '{print $2}' fileA`
do
   loc=`grep ${user} fileB | awk -F',' '{print $4}'`
   sed -i "/${user}/ s/$/,${loc}/" fileA
done
```

Adding the example:

```
$ cat fileA
,,"user1","email"
,,"user2","email"
,,"user3","email"
,,"user4","email"

$ cat fileB
,,user2,location2
,,user4,location4
,,user1,location1
,,user3,location3

$ for user in `awk -F\" '{print $2}' fileA`; do echo ${user}; loc=`grep ${user} fileB |    awk -F',' '{print $4}'`; echo ${loc}; sed -i "/${user}/ s/$/,${loc}/" fileA; done

$ cat fileA
,,"user1","email",location1
,,"user2","email",location2
,,"user3","email",location3
,,"user4","email",location4
```

The description is not clear but based on the question you can use the following command to append a value/data to end of each row in Unix

```
sed -i '/search_pattern/ s/$/string_to_be_appended/' filename
```

Comment: My bad for not clearly mentioning.
search fileA username onfileB and get location and add that location to fileA to the user row

Comment: Thank you Very much. It is working fine as per my requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely in `awk`

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{a[$3]=$4;next}
{for(x in a) if(index($3,x)>0) print $0","a[x]}' file2 file1
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file1
,,"user1","email"
,,"user2","email"
,,"user3","email"
,,"user4","email"

$ cat file2
,,user2,location2
,,user4,location4
,,user1,location1
,,user3,location3

$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$4;next}{for(x in a) if(index($3,x)>0) print $0","a[x]}' file2 file1
,,"user1","email",location1
,,"user2","email",location2
,,"user3","email",location3
,,"user4","email",location4
```